# inner workings of Mobile-net resolution multiplier - what does it do?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, convolution, image-size, image

i have a question concerning the way Mobile Net's resolution parameter works. From the [article itself](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04861.pdf) and from the blog posts on the topic ([1](https://hackernoon.com/creating-insanely-fast-image-classifiers-with-mobilenet-in-tensorflow-f030ce0a2991), [2](https://towardsdatascience.com/review-mobilenetv1-depthwise-separable-convolution-light-weight-model-a382df364b69)) I wasn't able to find an answer to my question. It is said that “the resolution multiplier changes the input dimensions of the image, reducing the internal representation at every layer”. Does that mean it (the parameter):

A) breaks down each image into a, for example, respective 224x224 bits of pixels sub-images, over which the network runs its convolution?

OR

B) takes one single 224x224 slice of pixels from, for example, the middle of the image, over which the network runs its convolutions?

OR

C) Squishes the original image into a, for example 224x224 pixel representation of itself, over which the network runs its convolutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the authors of the mobile net architecture and papers and they provided me with the following answer:

The multiplier accomplishes what is being articulated in C): it acts as a re-scaling of the original input image to fit the value specified by the parameter. The default image size is 224x244, which corresponds to a resolution multiplier of 1.0. So 112x112 input image resolution corresponds to a 0.5 resolution multiplier which is achieved by simply downscaling the image to 112x112. Technically we scale the smaller side to target and crop the other dimensions.

I hope this proves as helpful to others as it was to me.